# Pull Data From Web Database With Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, website, database, sql, 802.1x

I have a web based database that I work with regularly that uses 802.1x authentication (Smart Card with password). From the website you can pull premade and custom reports that are ultimately stored in an SQL database and they are displayed on a webpage.

I want to use Excel 2007 to pull real time data from the database or website instead of copying and pasting the data into an Excel workbook everyday. Multiple users would log in on multiple computers to access the Excel document and the document would need to be located on a shared network resource.

Is there any sort of solution?

I'm sure more information is required, so please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: If you can access the database through ODBC you could probably wire it up. But using a shared Excel document has it's own issues. A small web application would probably be the best bet.

Comment: Kindly have a look at this link http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pull-data-into-microsoft-excel-with-web-queries/6115870

Comment: *OP here* ^^I cannot access the database directly Brad Patton.  ^Thank you for the informative link Santosh.  My particular problem lies with the current active session that I have.  Once my session expires (maybe 10 minutes or so) the website will no longer work unless I log in through the normal web browser and activate my session again and update all the queries through Excel.  Then it works fine until the session expires again.